# I have problem to connect with sqlite_popen() with php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a problem with php and sqlite. I always have that warning:

Warning: sqlite_popen() [function.sqlite-open]: file is encrypted or is not a database.

the name I pass to connect is a database sqlite3. I don't know how to fix that ?

Comment: Does the PHP user (often, www-data) have read/write permissions to the database?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite_open() only supports sqlite2.

if you want to use sqlite3 you'll have to switch to PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have a database created with sqlite3 while the method call expects a sqlite (version 2) database. Try sqlite3 PHP API instead; here are the [docs](http://php-sqlite3.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/API).

Note that sqlite3 support is [compiled in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php) with PHP 5.3.0. Then something like

```
$db = sqlite3_open(":memory:");
```

should suffice.